# Types of relations

Tags: relations

Let  A= {x is reals:x>0} and define a relation on A by x relation y 
If xy=0 for x,y in A .

I was wondering if this is reflexive relation. So far I thought 
If x=1 and y= 0, then 1*0=0 and 
0*1 is also =0. It can be reflexive not sure if I am doing it right by using this counter example . How do I prove  what sort of relation it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not reflexive. If $x>0$, then $x\times x>0$. In particular, $x\times x\neq0$.

Comment: sorry I am little confused on how  prove what sort of relation it is .

Comment: Wasn't your question simply asking whether it is reflexive or not? Did I not answer that question?

Comment: Yes u did answer  it thanks.

Comment: @CS1 That is not the most adequate way to thank for a good answer. You should consider to mark it as correct and/or upvote it. Those are the ways of acknowledging the work others have done for you. Moreover, whenever you accept an answer, you also gain 2 points of reputation. That' often how it starts. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Let us call R the relation you are considering is.

By definition,

R = { (x,y) belonging to R² | x . y = 0}

**Let us think of this relation as a machine that selects pairs of real numbers in the plane R².** In other words, a machine that selects points in the plane R².

Certainly this machine selects all points that have 0 as X-coordinate. In other words, **all points belonging to the line x=0 are selected.** ( This line it nothing else but the Y-axis).

The machine also selects all points that have 0 as  Y-coordinate. In other words , **all points belonging to the line y=0 are selected**. ( This line is the X-axis itself).

**In order this relation to be reflexive, it should select all points on the line whose equation is  y = x.**

Is it the case?

No, the only point of the line with equation y=x that is selected by our " R-machine"  is the point (0,0) .

Pick at random any other point of the line with equation y=x, say the point

( 0, 00001; 0, 00001).

Is this point " selected" by our relation.

It would be  selected **IFF**  0, 00001 times  0, 00001 is equal to 0 ( Remember this is the sufficient and necessary condition to be " selected" by our "R-machine").

But obviously, this condition is not fullfilled! 0,00001 times 0,00001, as you know, is NOT equal to 0.

Conclusion: **failing to select all the points belonging to the line y=x, our relation is NOT reflexive.**